# Google play game Leaderboard can not submitScore

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am trying to submit a score at a Google Game Play Leaderboard using the following code line:

```
 if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(mGoogleApiClient, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", myScore).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.SubmitScoreResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Leaderboards.SubmitScoreResult arg0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getStatusCode= "+arg0.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                    Log.e(TAG, "score submitted: "+arg0.getScoreData().toString());
                }
            });
        }
```

The score is not uploaded and I get the following error `ScoreSubmissionData`:

```
ScoreSubmissionData{PlayerId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, StatusCode=2, TimesSpan=DAILY, Result=null, TimesSpan=WEEKLY, Result=null, TimesSpan=ALL_TIME, Result=null}

StatusCode=2 means STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED
```

I call the above line inside `onConnected()` method so it is sure that I am connected...

Answer (score 0):

Try reconnecting or apply a Loop-switch sequence to handle error like this. You might want to check this [example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient&method=STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) showing how to use **`STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED`** of the **`com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient`** class.

Base on the document:

> [**`STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED`**](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/appstate/AppStateClient.html#STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED)
>
> - The AppStateClient is in an inconsistent state and must reconnect to the service to resolve the issue.

Also here is the list of [**`AppStateClient`**](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/appstate/AppStateClient) that you may encounter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

The application i make was first build to an other Laptop.
Now i have bought a new Laptop, i installed Android Studio and tried to change some code lines. But when i submitted a Score my Google play account (API Manager) could not recognize my new Laptop because it had a different SHA1 key.
So i added my new SHA1 key at the credentials of the API Manager and everything was ok !!